# Angular repeater save $index in node prop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to take the $index from the repeater and save it on the current node in a prop called sort.

somehow like this

```
<li ng-repeat="node in rootNodeLst | orderBy:'node.Sort'" 
    ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" ng-mode=['node.Sort' = $index]></li>
```

where the line below shows what to focus on here.

> ng-mode=['node.Sort' = $index]

So. Take the ng-repeat index, and save it on the current child node's prop called Sort.

the reason behind this is that i need to have the sort updated when i move the elements in the `<li>`

can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In your ng-repeat directive add ng-init like this

```
<li ng-repeat="node in rootNodeLst" ng-init="node.Sort = $index">
  {{ node.Sort }}
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WeUeBxGBJVUYErWY3hAX

Comment: whats the use of this you can use directly {{$index}}